# Django Trailing Slash throws 404

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I have a django application with DRF and didn't change default APPEND_SLASH. Here is my url conf:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', SampleViewSet, 'sample')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sample/', include(router.urls))
]
```

So when I call the api from Browser as below,

```
api/v1/sample/1
```

it redirects the request with 304 to the

```
api/v1/sample/1/
```

which throws 404. I have the resource in db for sure.

Not sure where my mistake is. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you add the 404 response?

Comment: Where's your router urls file?